# How to print the full PHP code generated right before compile (after includes and requires)?

Tags: php, php-include

Is there a way to print full php (in php) code after includes and requires?

For example I have 3 files.

File `basic.php`

```
<?php echo 2; include 'basic2.php'; ?>
```

File `basic2.php`

```
<?php echo 3; ?>
```

and the main file `main_file.php`

```
<?php echo 1; include 'basic.php'; echo 4; ?>
```

I would like to get the full code that would be about to be compiled, the result would be something like this:

```
<?php echo 1; ?><?php echo 2; ?><?php echo 3; ?><?php echo 4; ?>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this. The `php` command has an option to display the source with syntax highlighting, and an option to display it with comments and excess whitespace removed, but I don't see an option to display it with include files merged.

Comment: @Barmar is right. You misunderstood Fred

Comment: A problem with trying to do this is that it may have to execute the script to get the include files, because the filenames don't have to be literals.

Comment: That's a good point @Fred-ii, but in my case my includes are always literal, I'm trying to make a single file with all the content.

Comment: Maybe you can find a 3rd-party tool that does it. It might be part of a PHP cross-reference package, or some PHP IDE. Try asking on [Software Recommendation](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: @Barmar: that's correct. Even if the filenames are literals, `require/include` statements are processed *during execution*, not at *parse time*. For normal code like `echo 1`, the parser generates instructions for the Zend VM to output the number 1, but `require` instructs the VM to "load this file and parse it" - at the moment `main_file.php` is fully parsed and the VM starts executing it, it still doesn't know anything about the contents of `basic.php`. See [demo on 3v4l](http://3v4l.org/ijb3c/vld#tabs).